# Intellisense support for JQuery in vs 2008 isn't working

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I've followed every steps in [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx), but still, the Intellisense for JQuery simply isn't working, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [got the problem solved](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2008/11/potential-jquery-intellisenses-bug.html). It turns out that I didn't reference the JQuery script file properly.

Answer (score 2):

When I added the update for jquery intellisense to vwd2008, it wouldn't work on some of my existing projects.

Turns out that the ui.datepicker.js plugin I was using was causing the intellisense to fall over.

I hid the ui.datepicker.js file from the intellisense by creating a dummy file in as outlined in point 8 in this guide

[jQuery Intellisense Guide](http://blogs.gotdotnet.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/18/jscript-intellisense-faq.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Jim3

Answer (score 1):

Download the jquery documentation from [here](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.2.6-vsdoc.js) and place it in the same directory as the file called 'jquery-1.2.6.pack.js'.  Restart VS, and you should now have intellisense working. VS looks for a file with a '-vsdoc' at the end of the filename to provide intellisense.  There's over 5000 lines in there, but if you're comfortable navigating through it then you can actually alter the intellisense hints to suit yourself.

If that doesn't work for you, then try [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736) MS patch to help make VS recognise the -vsdoc files for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had to reload the files or the project or something to get it working.  IME it's a bit like all MS Intellisense - you never quite know if you're going to get anything or what it's going to be...

No doubt JetBrains and WholeTomato will along soon enough to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this VS2008 hotfix:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736

and it solved my issue, I tried to rename the vsdoc2 file to vsdoc and it did not help but the hotfix solved it.